# Convert a script into macOS application?

Tags: python, applescript

I have been looking up how to convert a .py script into an .app application so the users know how to run it. So far I have only found using py2app or pyinstaller. Is there a significant disadvantage using an application generated by exporting the following script into application and putting my python script into the application's resource folder? (My python script has a GUI and only uses a built-in library in python 2.7.)

```applescript
tell application "Finder"
    if exists POSIX file "/Applications/app.app/Contents/Resources/appname.py" then
        tell application "Terminal"
            do script "python /Applications/app.app/Contents/Resources/appname.py"
        end tell
    else if exists POSIX file "/Volumes/appname/appname.py" then
        tell application "Terminal"
            do script "python /Volumes/appname/appname.py"
        end tell
    else
        display dialog "Please copy the file to the Application folder, or mount the installation diskimage"
    end if
end tell
tell application "Terminal"
    close
end tell
```

It works fine on my computer, so I am just curious why I couldn't find it on the Internet.

Comment: I don't know if python is built-in to Mac OS, but I doubt it is. When you use things like py2app they bundle the whole python interpreter with your program. This means that your 5KiB script is now a 35MiB application. On an OS with Python built-in, that's just a waste. Which doesn't really matter, except for maybe download time. So, something to be aware of, but not really something you have a choice in probably.

Comment: @GRAYgoose124 Python 2.7 is built-in, you can simply type "python" into terminal to use it. BTW, tkinter 8.5.9 is also built-in in macOS.

Comment: In that case, what you can do is rename it to a *.pyw file so that the terminal won't show and then put `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of it. (Assuming this is a single file, if not it'd still work but I'd see why you want to bundle it then) then it's runnable just by clicking, I assume you could copy it to the Applications menu too. The shebang line tells the OS which program to use to run the current file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things I would advise.

- Use `path to current application` so that you have the path no matter
  where the app is.
- What may be "cleaner" is, instead of using the Terminal, use `do shell script` like:

  `do shell script "/path/to/my/script/script.py"`

as long as the script is "chmod"-ed to be executable (I also like using a utility called "Kilometre" for this)

Apart from that, there's nothing dangerous or wrong about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you very much! So I changed my script into `tell application "Finder"
 set current_path to container of (path to me) as alias
end tell

do shell script POSIX path of current_path & "myscript.py"`but it said "sh:permission denied." I have no idea why because the software is on my desktop. And asking the user for sudo permission will sometimes scare them.

Comment: Ok I solved it. I just found online how to convert a script into executable. I don't use terminal a lot so I did not understand what you were referring to by "chmod."  Thank you!

Comment: No problem. It's totally worth teaching yourself (or otherwise learning) the shell (terminal).